# Get data from dynamic radiobutonlist,dropdownlist, textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

hy guys

I have a method that reads data from database, and after that creates some controls that user should populate then (textbox, radiobuttonlist..)

```
      var collection = new List<string>();
        OracleConnection conn = this.ApplicationContext.GetConnection(CrmContext.ConnectionEnum.CrmDatabase);
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        string sql = some query;
        OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(sql, conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        Table tbl = new Table();
        TableRow tr;
        TableCell tc;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {

            tr = new TableRow();
            tc = new TableCell();
            tc.Text = dr["display_name"].ToString() + ": ";
            tr.Controls.Add(tc);

            switch (dr["input_type"].ToString())
            {
                case "TXT":
                    tc = new TableCell();
                    TextBox txt = new TextBox();
                    txt.ID =  dr["name"].ToString();
                    txt.Text = "";
                    tc.Controls.Add(txt);
                    tr.Controls.Add(tc);
                    tbl.Controls.Add(tr);
                    collection.Add(txt.ID);
                    kontrole.Add(txt.Text.ToString());
                    break;

                case "RBL":
                    tc = new TableCell();
                    string[] options = dr["options"].ToString().Split(',');
                    RadioButtonList rbl = new RadioButtonList();
                    for (int i = 0; i < options.Length; i++)
                    {
                        rbl.Items.Add(new ListItem(options[i], i.ToString()));
                    }
                    rbl.ID= dr["name"].ToString();
                    tc.Controls.Add(rbl);
                    tr.Controls.Add(tc);
                    tbl.Controls.Add(tr);
                    collection.Add(rbl.ID);
                    kontrole.Add(rbl.SelectedValue.ToString());
                    break;               
            }
        }
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tbl);
        ControlsCollection = collection;
```

this is the part where I create the controls

I have another button save on form, and on that click I should read the data from the created controls and call samo other method, but I can't do that

I tried recreating controls with List, but it worked only for textboxes

recreating controls is not a must, it would be enough just to get control.id value( textbox.text, radiobuttonlist.selectedindex)

any tips on how to get that values?

I've been trying to get it done with viewstate but radiobuttonlist is giving me a trouble

Answer (score 0):

You're better off putting things into a `GridView` rather than dynamically creating a table, it'll give you a bit more control and is generally nicer to work with.

Once you have your GridView (or if you insist, just adapt the following), on PostBack/Click event you can do something like this :

```
protected void MyLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow gvr in MyGridView.Rows)
    {
        int radioItemValue = 0;
        string radioItemText = "";

        foreach (DataControlFieldCell dc in gvr.Cells)
        {
            string cellName = dc.ContainingField.ToString();
            string cellText = dc.Text;
            switch (cellName)
            {
                case ("MyColumnNameWithRadioButtonList"):
                    try
                    {
                        var tb = (TextBox)gvr.FindControl("MyTextBox");
                        var rbl = (RadioButtonList)gvr.FindControl("MyRadioButtonList");
                        var rb = (ListControl)rbl;
                        radioItemValue = Convert.ToInt32(rb.SelectedValue);
                        radioItemText = rb.SelectedItem.Text;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //error trapping required?
                    }
                    break;
                case ("AnotherColumn"):
                    //do some other stuff?
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Remember, if you have dynamically created controls you will need to recreate them on PostBack otherwise their events will not fire.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a little hacky, but you basically can collect control values from the posted form itself. For that you need to have a list of their names though. For a server-side control name attribute is filled out with `ClientID` field of the control, and this field is accessible only after the PreRender. I assume that you create your controls earlier than the PreRender is run, so suggestion is like that.

Have a field on the page to contain all dynamically created controls:

```
private List<Control> controls = new List<Control>();
```

while you are creating controls, make sure to add them to this list:

```
tc.Controls.Add(txt);
tr.Controls.Add(tc);
tbl.Controls.Add(tr);

controls.Add(txt); // the same for other types of course
```

And in PreRender collect `ClientID` from these controls and store it in the view state:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object source, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> ids = controls.Select(c => c.ClientID).ToList();
    ViewState["controls"] = ids;
}
```

Now after the post back occurs, you need to read the form values:

```
List<string> ids = ViewState["controls"] as List<string>;
if (ids != null)
{
    foreach (string id in ids)
    {
        string value = Request.Form[id];
        //do whatever you need with the value
    }
}
```